# How to restructuring the data by the data's property in Django-Rest-Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Disk serializer, my Disk serializer is bellow :

```
class DiskSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    diskessencetype_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='diskEssenceType.name')
    diskostype_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='diskOsType.name')
    class Meta:
        model = Disk
        fields = [
            "id",
            "price",
            "diskessencetype_name",
            "diskostype_name",
        ]
```

The views.py is bellow:

```
class DiskListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = DiskSerializer
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = Disk.objects.all()
```

And  that generate the data like bellow:

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "price": "5.00",
        "diskessencetype_name": "ssd",
        "diskostype_name": "系统盘"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "price": "6.00",
        "diskessencetype_name": "sas",
        "diskostype_name": "系统盘"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "price": "5.00",
        "diskessencetype_name": "sas",
        "diskostype_name": "数据盘"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "price": "6.00",
        "diskessencetype_name": "sas",
        "diskostype_name": "系统盘"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "price": "6.00",
        "diskessencetype_name": "sas",
        "diskostype_name": "系统盘"
    },
  .....
  ]
```

But I want to search out and constraints to bellow data:

```
{
    "系统盘":[{"id":5, "diskessencetype_name":"sas", "price":5.00},.....]
    "数据盘":[{"id":7, "diskessencetype_name":"ssd", "price":7.00},.....]
}
```

You see, they are restructuring by the instance's property(`diskostype_name`), is there a build-in method to realizer it?

How can I rebuild them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**views.py**

```
class Postlar(ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = []
    queryset = Disk.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DiskSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        result = {}
        SerializerClass = self.get_serializer_class()
        for u in ["系统盘", "数据盘"]:
            serializer = SerializerClass(Disk.objects.filter(diskOsType__name=u), many=True)
            result[u] = serializer.data

        return Response(result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can I know your facebook id?

Comment: Can I make the logic in Serializer?